# How quickly and efficiently the OS can free up the cached RAM?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, memory

I know about the concept of "Free RAM is wasted RAM". My question is how quickly and efficiently the OS can free up the cached RAM, so that apps have enough RAM in time of a spike in usage.

We have a web app hosted in linux. We normally have 10-20% memory utilisation. But we see spikes up to about 100% when certain parts of the code is invoked.(Code has been max optimised).I want to trigger an email when this happens. Should I write a script to monitor memory utilisation including Cache or just the application memory ?

When the Out of Memory error occurs in linux, does it means cache memory is zero and all the RAM has been already allocated to applications ?

Answer (score 1):

Yes it means the OS has cleared all the memory it used for filesystem caching. Basically your webserver/app is doing a `malloc` for a certain amount of memory and the kernel frees the memory and gives it to the app to use. This is an atomic call and doesn't block the app at all.

You simply need more memory in the server or handle less connections.

Answer (score 0):

When an OOM event like the OOM killer happens all RAM and swap is used, buffers and cache are at minimum, and you already have poor performance. Keep memory use below 100%.

On Linux, you can [interpret /proc/meminfo](https://access.redhat.com/solutions/406773)

`MemAvailable` is an estimate of how much can be allocated without swapping

`MemFree + Buffers + Cached` is effectively free.